# What does this phrase mean? [ Ты здал его шарадами?]

Tags: перевод, значения

I received it in a congratulations card from a relative who knows I'm learning Russian. I tried to translate it but the best I got was '*Have you [verb]ed him with the charades?*' The phrase is (to my best knowledge):

> Ты здал его шарадами?

*Здал* doesn't seem to be a verb, interestingly (at least not on Wiktionary).

Is it an idiom, or just an unusual way of putting things? Thanks a lot for any help - it would be much appreciated.

Comment: That doesn't sound like any idiom I know and to be honest, this sentence doesn't make any sense and looks like it could be not in Russian language at all but probably in some other Slavic language. There is no such word as 'здал' in Russian, it looks more like an incorrect spelling of 'сдал' - past participle third person masculine of 'сдать' - 'to pass' as in 'to pass an exam'. 'Charades' is self explanatory. Translated directly it sounds like - 'You passed it with/by charades'. It doesn't make any sense. Maybe the person meant something like 'Passed with flying colors'?

Comment: Most probable, thanks - I did just pass an exam. Mystery solved.

Comment: @ermatveit: what exactly do you mean by "to my best knowledge"? Was it not written on the card?

Comment: "здал " - just an error.  "Сдал" is the correct form (and this "сдал" is near to slang too).  "здал" - or the parody on the error/slang of illiterate humans...

Comment: "ты сдал его шарадами" sounds like "you betrayed him using the riddles(charades)"  ;
"Did you give him charades?" - mb, this "здал" as an incorrect form "дал" ? (to give) ? In this case all in the sentence and cases is mistaken. "Ты дал ему шарады ?" is right. Also - there is the "ждал" (to wait)... "Ты ждал его с шарадами" - "Are you wating him with charades ?" - or mb he means - "Are you waiting it with this charade?" - "Ты ждал это с такой шарадой ?", "Ждал такую шараду?" :))

Comment: Yes it's just they were copying out from a website about Russian cursive, I'm guessing, as they don't learn Russian, so it was a little difficult to make out.

Answer (score 1):

This probably should be not здал but задал.

Ну, ты и задал ему шараду.
(Шарада here is задачка, a puzzle or a а problem) and the whole meaning is "you surprised him'

Comment: this is not a question, but the сharade :>

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is certainly misspelled (there is no prefix *з-*) and likely malformed. Possible mistakes could be:

- Using the word *сдал* instead of *справился* and then misspelling it as *здал*: *Ты справился с его шарадами?* Did you manage to solve his charades?
- Misspelling *закидал* as *здал*: *Ты закидал его шарадами?* Have you bombarded him with charades?